# StochPy missing module when using PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I use PyDev in Eclipse for Python coding. I need to use the `Stochpy` package. I already have it installed and it works fine in the Command Prompt. However, it gives me `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSA'"` error when running in Eclipse.
Why is that?

The code is as simple as:

```
import stochpy
smod = stochpy.SSA()
```

The second line gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSA'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `from stochpy import stochpy`? You can also run into this error if your filename is the same as the module you're trying to import.

Comment: Another possible issue could be that you're adding the wrong path to the PYTHONPATH...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did have a file that have the same module name... PyCharm give me error like "imported resolves to its containing file", which is easier to understand for me.